# Realvnc file transfer is being silently truncated

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, realvnc

I'm trying to transfer a ~2MB file from VNC to my PC and failing miserably - the file that comes through is maybe 40KB. Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere?

Details: I'm running VNC Viewer P4.3.2 on Windows 7 Home Premium. The remote computer is running VNC Server, also P4.3.2, on Windows Server 2003. File transfer used to work just fine on my old (Windows XP) computer, but it died, and I now have this lovely Windows 7 box. I've tried toggling the "enable file transfer" checkbox in the VNC Viewer options, it didn't help. The server has been running just fine for years, so I'm thinking the problem must lie somewhere in Windows 7; perhaps it's that the OS is 64-bit but VNC Viewer is running as 32-bit?

(By "silently truncated", I mean that I do the usual 'copy on the server, paste on the desktop', and it all looks peachy... that is until I try to open the file.)

Comment: I was about to say: are you sure you're not trying to transfer some shortcut? But given Tom's answer I guess the solution has been found.

Comment: I've never met a shortcut that was larger than 2KB. 40KB is definitely not a shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft introduced a bug in the software interface (APIs) used to supply file data to the shell for the Paste operation, which causes files to be truncated when fetched to Vista SP1 & above.  More recent versions of VNC Enterprise & Personal Editions have a workaround for this to fix file-transfers.

You can get support via http://www.realvnc.com/support.html.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like this is exactly what my problem is. However, I can't actually find any documentation of the bug on either realvnc's site or Microsoft's. Do you have any direct links?

Comment: Can't find anything substantial on it now, just a minor note in the RealVNC 4.4.0 release notes:
  "FIXED: File transfer truncating files on Vista SP 1."
     -- http://www.realvnc.com/products/enterprise/4.4/release-notes.html